# How to group by date and name in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Actually what I want to get is quite simple, I want to get the first login and the last logout from a user, per day. In oder to get that I have a database where I can make SQLQueries but I'm not able to get the result that I want. 
I will explain it with this example:

```
 (NAME-LOGIN-LOGOUT)
| AAAAAAAAAAAA       | 23/02/2012 10:33:56,323 | 23/02/2012 16:03:10,323
| AAAAAAAAAAAA       | 24/02/2012 07:59:55,787 | 24/02/2012 13:32:16,787
| AAAAAAAAAAAA       | 24/02/2012 13:34:15,823 | 24/02/2012 15:00:54,823
| AAAAAAAAAAAA       | 27/02/2012 08:00:24,283 | 27/02/2012 16:00:14,283
| AAAAAAAAAAAA       | 28/02/2012 07:56:26,78  | 28/02/2012 13:09:16,78
| AAAAAAAAAAAA       | 28/02/2012 13:09:58,287 | 28/02/2012 15:09:08,287
| AAAAAAAAAAAA       | 29/02/2012 07:52:47,82  | 29/02/2012 16:03:37,82
| AAAAAAAAAAAA       | 22/02/2012 10:15:25,817 | 22/02/2012 10:24:42,817
| BBBBBBBBBBBB       | 20/02/2012 07:22:50,31  | 24/02/2012 14:16:43,31
| CCCCCCCCCCCC       | 15/02/2012 07:58:33,777 | 15/02/2012 16:02:53,777
| CCCCCCCCCCCC       | 16/02/2012 08:00:56,29  | 16/02/2012 15:03:06,29
| CCCCCCCCCCCC       | 17/02/2012 07:57:31,29  | 17/02/2012 16:00:34,29
| CCCCCCCCCCCC       | 20/02/2012 08:01:01,82  | 20/02/2012 15:00:09,82
| CCCCCCCCCCCC       | 21/02/2012 07:59:57,29  | 21/02/2012 14:40:13,29
```

The result I want to get (e.g for user A) using the SQL sentece with the groupby attribute is:

(Result should show just the first login and the last logout of the day)

```
USER
{
    DATE
    {
      min(Login);
      max(LogOut);
    }
}



(NAME-LOGIN-LOGOUT)
AAAAAAAAAAAAA  23/02/2012 10:33:56,323   23/02/2012 16:03:10,323
AAAAAAAAAAAAA  24/02/2012 07:59:55,787   24/02/2012 15:00:54,823
AAAAAAAAAAAAA  27/02/2012 08:00:24,283   27/02/2012 16:00:14,283
AAAAAAAAAAAAA  28/02/2012 07:56:26,78    28/02/2012 15:09:08,287
.....
```

I guess that is using several select or conditions but I'm not able to get it work.
I would really appreciate any help.

---

I came up with the following answer but I'm still getting the mininum and maximun value of the   last row when I make the group by. It seems that is making first the Group by and afterwards get the max and min values. I would like to be the other way around :) , first get the max and min taking into account the date and user and then group by user and date.

```
SELECT EnterpriseName, LoginDate, LogOutDate, min(LoginTime), max(LogOutTime)
FROM
ipcc_table
WHERE LoginDate=LogOutDate
GROUP BY  EnterpriseName,LoginDate;
```

best regards

Comment: What happens when the user logs in on one day, but logs out the next day? Are you considering only the day on which a user logs in?

Comment: You can see what David is mentioning with user `BB..`. What would you expect if you have another entry for that user?

Comment: Actually I haven't noticed about that issue, I guess that if there's a login for a day but not logout, I would add an entry in the sql database with the logout as 23:59:59 of that day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to get the first login and logout from a certain user, per day.

```
SELECT name
      ,date(login) AS day
      ,min(login)  AS login
      ,min(logout) AS logout
FROM   tbl
WHERE  name = <my_name>
GROUP  BY name, date(login)
ORDER  BY name, date(login);
```

The [`date()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) should be the most fitting tool here.

This does not take into account that the first logout could be before the first login or multiple sessions could be intertwined. But your question does ask for this.

---

If you actually want the first login *and the accompanying logout* from a certain user, per day:

```
SELECT i.name, i.day, i.login, o.logout
FROM  (
   SELECT name
         ,date(login) AS day
         ,min(login)  AS login
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  name = <my_name>
   GROUP  BY name, date(login)
   )   i
JOIN   tbl o USING (name, login)
ORDER  BY i.name, i.login;
```

This assumes that `(name, login)` is unique. If it isn't you really should add a surrogate primary key, like an auto-increment column.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do something like

```
select name, min(login), min(logout), trunc(login)
group by name, trunc(login)
```

trunc is probably oracle specific and turns (among other things) a date with time in just a date. Something like this is bound to be available in your RDBMS as well.

Comment: The MySql version would be DATE().

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(login, '%d/%m/%Y') AS day, MIN(login) AS first_login, MAX(logout) AS last_logout
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY name, day
```

I believe that is valid MySQL syntax, but I'm not absolutely certain (I don't have a test platform). Note that the date of the last logout could be different than the date of the login.

Answer (score 0):

`QUOTE from OP`: "I want to get the first `login` and `logout` from a **certain user**, **per day**   "

```
SELECT `name`, MIN(`login`), MAX(`logout`) 
FROM table WHERE name = 'AAAA' GROUP BY YEAR(`login`), MONTH(`login`), DAY(`login`)
```

Comment: I think you want to `GROUP BY name` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY login
```

Then you get last login, if you add DESC you get first login.

Answer (score 0):

(making an assumption on what you want to happen when `DATE(login) < DATE(logout)` ):

```
    SELECT
        name
      , login
      , logout
    FROM
        tableX
    WHERE
        DATE(login) < DATE(logout)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        name
      , MIN(login) 
      , MAX(logout) 
    FROM 
        tableX
    GROUP BY 
        name
      , DATE(login)
    HAVING 
        DATE(MIN(login)) = DATE(MAX(logout))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear as to what should happen when the logout date is different to the login date so I have compensated for both scenarios.

Where you want the first login of each day, and the last logout of any day, regardless of the Login Date.

```
SELECT  Name,
        COALESCE(MIN(Login), EventDate) AS Login,
        COALESCE(MAX(LogOut), ADDTIME(EventDate, '23:59:59'))  AS LogOut
FROM    (   SELECT  Name,
                    DATE(Login) AS EventDate,
                    MIN(LogIn) AS Login,
                    NULL AS LogOut
            FROM    TestTable
            GROUP BY Name, DATE(Login)
            UNION
            SELECT  Name,
                    DATE(LogOut) AS EventDate,
                    NULL AS Login,
                    MAX(LogOut) AS LogOut
            FROM    TestTable
            GROUP BY Name, DATE(Login)
        ) AS d
GROUP BY Name, EventDate;
```

So for 'BBBBBBBBBBBB' above this would return

```
BBBBBBBBBBBB    2012-02-20 07:22:50  2012-02-20 23:59:59
BBBBBBBBBBBB    2012-02-24 00:00:00  2012-02-24 14:16:43
```

Alternatively for a simpler method:

```
SELECT  Name,
        MIN(Login) AS Login,
        MAX(Logout) AS LogOut
FROM    TestTable
GROUP BY Name, DATE(Login)
```

which for 'BBBBBBBBBBBB' above this would return

```
BBBBBBBBBBBB    2012-02-20 07:22:50   2012-02-24 14:16:43
```